# WP Template Hierarchy - Need help choosing the correct templates

Tags: pages, page-template, template-hierarchy

Please see this [image](http://83338.com/aspen.jpg) to get a better understanding of what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Please pay attention to point #3 and #4 (notice the permalink structure).

- The "Homepage" is static (front-page.php).
- The "Resort" page provides an overview Aspen (page-aspen.php).
- The "Property Type" page should list all properties in Aspen.
- The "Property Name" page is a landing page for the property.

What template do you recommend I use for point #3 and #4?

Thanking in advance!

Comment: "Please pay attention" Please be considerate to others. You will also need to add much more info. Are your posts custom post types, taxonomies, terms? How are these posts related to each other?

Comment: Hi Pieter thank you for your interest.  At this point I am really not sure if I should use custom post types or taxonomies.  I am hoping that someone can give me some input based on the required permalink structure.

Comment: How do you need this to operate? A hierarchical CPT would do this more or less out of the box, but you would need to manually create a lot of pages (and you can have trouble with large hierarchical post types).

Comment: @PieterGoosen : I don't see "Please pay attention" as inconsiderate. It reads like "Let me point out the two issues I am specifically concerned about" to me.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I just think "Let me point out the two issues I am specifically concerned about" reads better. Just my opinion. Not very fond of "Please pay attention"

Comment: Please pardon my English! Here is a website that achieves a similar goal [link](http://www.alpineguru.com/chalets/united-states/aspen/chalet-chantal/)

Comment: I really think this is primarily opinion based. You will have to sit down and work out how you will structure your posts first, are you going to use CPT's, custom taxonomies, etc etc. This will all depend on your own needs